# Icon animation disables my navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, icons, navbar

I have this issue: I've animated an arrow pointing down and placed it under the "login" in my navbar, but it seems that when the animation gets close tu the "login", I can't press, like it's blocking it somehow, is there a way to fix this? Or should I remove the animation?

[This is what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDGI1.png)

```css
body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: white;
}

.circle {
position: absolute;
top: 10%;
left: 83.5%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 110px;
color: white;
font-size: 30px;
overflow: hidden;
color: yellow;
}

.circle  {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
animation: animate 1s infinite;
right: 0;
}

@keyframes animate {
50%{
transform: translateX(-50px);
margin-top: -30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<header>

  <div class="container">
    <img src="img1.png" style="max-width: 80px; margin-top: 0px;" alt="logo" class="logo">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">INICIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACTO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">REGISTRATE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">INGRESAR</a></li>
        <div class="circle">
    <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
      </ul>

      </div>

    </nav>


</header>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've forgotten to do that, it's fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you could make use of CSS pointer-events

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

If you set `pointer-events:none;` for the css element, it won't block links it covers.

Example:

```
.circle{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've fixed it

Comment: I used pointer-events: none; sure, I'm new here so I still forget to do that stuff.

Comment: Hey thanks. Glad you got through with your code. Have a great day!

Comment: You too, kind person!